# Getstream.io chat message search syntax

Tags: getstream-io

I am trying to implement a message search with getstream.io's chat product. 
[The docs](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/search/?language=js) have this example:

```js
const filters = { members: { $in: ['john'] } };

const search = await client.search(
   filters,
   'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious',
   { limit: 2, offset: 0 },
);
```

When I implement this, will get back messages that exactly match `supercalifragilisticexpialidocious` by user `john`, but based on testing in my app, I will not get John's messages that contain the string, for example: `supercalifragilisticexpialidocious is a fun thing to say`.

Is message search only set up for exact matches? Or is there a different syntax for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search works fine. This question is moot.